# How to delete or modify a database table using Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to delete or modify a table using flask-sqlalchemy?

I am working on a Flask-based web app. I switched to flask-sqlalchemy as my project is on Heroku and I had to connect my table to Heroku PostgreSQL. I made a flask-sqlalchemy table and created it using the `db.create_all()` command.

Now, for my app to fulfill its purpose, it is of utmost importance to save images, the best way of which I found to be to add them to the database.

Now, I want to change the particular table class to store a column called image as `image = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)` but I cannot. The former schema is unchanged and it gives me an error signifying that the column `image` does not exist every time I try to access or add something to the table.

How to do this?

Comment: Remember that SqlAlchemy is not a database.  It's just a database adapter.  You can always use the `psql` command line to work directly with your tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use drop()

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("...")
my_table.__table__.drop(engine)
```

Comment: This is really the right answer.  Will SqlAlchemy recreate the table in its new form next time it runs?

Comment: No.. you might need to look into migrations for that